# HttpResponseRedirect not changing webpage

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I have a webpage that creates and saves data to a database. To save the data, the user must hit the save button and I want to redirect from the create/save webpage to the success webpage that just says "success!"

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def save(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rawdata1 = request.body
        rawdata2 = json.loads(rawdata1)
        length = len(rawdata2)
        for i in range(0,length,1):
            x = meterdata(time_elapsed=rawdata2[i]['time_elapsed'], volts=rawdata2[i]['volts'], amps=rawdata2[i]['amps'], kW=rawdata2[i]['kW'], kWh=rawdata2[i]['kWh'], session=rawdata2[i]['session'])
            x.save()        
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('meter:success'))

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html')
```

In the developer tools I can see the post to the database (I have also checked it is saving data), and I can see success.html returned in the response but the actual web browser does not navigate to the webpage /sessionsimulator/success.

Comment: Is the `save` being called via ajax?

Comment: *Please* don't run a loop over `range(length)`. Just do `for data in rawdata2` and then use `data['time_elapsed']` etc.

Comment: @karthikr I am new to this whole web development so I'm not sure what exactly is happening. I am using YUI (Y.io) to make the post request. Does that help you at all?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Done. Sorry this took much longer than I planned and by the time I wrote that loop I was out of my mind. I have updated the code with your suggestion and agree it is much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: Yeah.. So, if you are using javascript libraries to do the post, `HttpResponseRedirect` does not work. You need to send back the URL in the context, and do `window.location.href=<url in context>`

Comment: Is there an easier way maybe just to bring up an alert that it was successful?

Comment: Yes - In the [success handler](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/), just alert a message.

Comment: @karthikr want to post an answer? I added three lines of code to my javascript file and  I know have a success indication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using javascript libraries to do the post, `HttpResponseRedirect` would not work.

Alternatively, you can send back the success message (or the URL) as a response and then in the success handler ([io.success](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/)) either `alert` the success message, or to redirect
to the desired page.